Take one value from dataframe
Have a problem with taking one value from df.
I want to make print with top 3 genres like this:
"TOP 3 most popular genres NA: Action, Sports, Shooter"
df = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')

genre_sales = df.groupby('Genre')['NA_Sales'].sum()
sorted_genre_sales = genre_sales.sort_values(ascending=False)
top3_genres = sorted_genre_sales.head(3)
print(top3_genres)

Output:
Genre
Action     877.83
Sports     683.35
Shooter    582.60

I have tried to use:
print(f'TOP 3 most popular genres NA: {top3_genres.iat[1,1]}')

Output:
TypeError: Series._get_value() got multiple values for argument 'takeable'


print(f'TOP 3 most popular genres NA: {top3_genres['Genre'][1]}')

Output:
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'Genre'
KeyError: 'Genre'

print(f'TOP 3 most popular genres NA: {top3_genres.iat['Genre'][1]}')

Output:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

print(f'TOP 3 most popular genres NA: {top3_genres.iat[1][1]}')

Output:
Exception has occurred: IndexError
invalid index to scalar variable.


Try print(f'TOP 3 most popular genres NA: {', '.join(top3_genres.index.to_list())}')

You have a pandas series with the name of genres, but you really want are the indexes in that pd.Series.

The values you are interested in printing are in the index of top3_genres.  You can access it via:
print(top3_genres.index.to_list())

If you want to print them stacked, you can join them with a newline character:
print('\n'.join(top3_genres.index))


Thx, friend.
Used your advice like this:
print(', '.join(top3_genres.index))

Now output is correct and written in a line.

Does this help?:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genere': ['Action', 'Sports', 'Shooter'],
                  'Column B': [877.83,683.35,582.60]})
df.head(3)['Genere'].to_list()


Yeah, but it returns list type object with quotation marks, and I was needed just clear Values
